# Can GetOpenFileName limit the file selection to files that match the filter?

Tags: c, winapi, getopenfilename

I'm using GetOpenFileName with an OPENFILENAME structure that uses lpstrFilter to filter the files to *.JPG.  However, in the file open dialog, for the File name, the user can type in *.XLS and see every Excel file in the same folder and choose to open an XLS file.  I want to prevent the user from doing this.  I want to really restrict them to only being able to pick JPG files for example.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there's a way; but even it there was, then nothing will stop the user from renaming an xls file to jpg. Or to open a broken jpeg downloaded on a flaky connection or saved on a broken USB key. The filter list is just a convenience to help the user to pick the "right" files, if he wants to feed your application garbage there's always a way. Ultimately, you'll always need to have code that handles gracefully the fact that the file that has been given to you isn't actually what you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `OPENFILENAME` struct, enable the `OFN_EXPLORER` and `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` flags, and provide a pointer to an [Explorer-style callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646931.aspx) in the `lpfnHook` field.  When the callback receives the [`CDN_FILEOK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646857.aspx) notification, you can validate the entered file(s) (not just the filename(s), but even the actual file content, if so desired) and then return an appropriate return value to accept/reject the selection:

> If the hook procedure returns zero, the dialog box accepts the specified file name and closes.
>
> To reject the specified file name and force the dialog box to remain open, return a nonzero value from the hook procedure and call the [`SetWindowLong`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591.aspx) function to set a nonzero `DWL_MSGRESULT` value.

Comment: You also need the `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` flag, otherwise `lpfnHook` will be ignored.